# Electron: prevent / cancel page navigation

Tags: redirect, events, navigation, electron

Is there anyway to prevent or cancel page navigation in electron?

```
win.webContents.on('did-start-loading', function(event, url) {
    if (event.sender.getURL().startsWith('http://xyz')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

The code above doesn't work since the event handler gets executed while the page keeps on navigating away.

Similarly, I'd also like to do the same for event 'did-get-redirect-request', to prevent certain redirect from happening.

Many thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`will-navigate`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#event-will-navigate) event to stop navigation.

You can also prevent requests (including redirects) using [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest()`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-request/#webrequestonbeforerequestfilter-listener):

```
const {session} = require('electron')
const ses = session.defaultSession
const urlToBlock = 'whatever'
ses.webRequest.onBeforeRequest((details, callback) => {
if (details.url === urlToBlock) // cancel the request
  callback({ cancel: true })
else // let the request happen
  callback({})
})
```

If you want to block all redirects you can add a listener to [`webRequest.onBeforeRedirect()`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-request/#webrequestonbeforeredirectfilter-listener) and add the redirect URL to a list of blocked URLs that you can then check in the listener you add to `webRequest.onBeforeRequest()`.

Comment: Links are still going through, but it did block devtools LOL

Answer (score 4):

This will prevent any links from navigating you to a different page inside an electron app.

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
win = new BrowserWindow()
win.webContents.on('will-navigate', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

This solution allows for devtools to be on too.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenerio I've fixed it like below

```
// just for demonstration what is mainWindow like
let mainWindow: BrowserWindow;

mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
  if (url.indexOf('#localhost/orgs/') !== -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not it. This is for new windows, not links